# react native flatlist with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-flatlist

rendering :

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => 
    <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

my method :

```
displayCollectionUser().then((collection) => {
    this.setState({
        data: Object.values(collection)
    });
    console.log("this.state.data");
    console.log(this.state.data);
});
```

Problem: 
children not display 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hello your `data` from `FlatList` has to be an `Array`. Your response is an `Object`.

`this.state.data` has to be an array. You can change your response to be an array, or move the object properties to an array. 
Just use this :

```
this.setState({
  data: Object.values(collection)
})
```

Comment: Can you show us how your `this.state.data` looks now? it should be an array.

Comment: So, you have a list of object. Try to use `{item.bouteille.bouche}`. What is that `key` from your answer?

Comment: where did i use this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183964/discussion-between-oma-and-thibaut-chazalon).